# Powershell - Regular expression for restrict uppercase and first lowercase followed by anything from lowercase and digit only

Tags: regex, powershell

I am accepting a parameter to PSH file and validating using `ValidatePattern`.

Regular expression should restrict uppercase and first lowercase followed by anything from lowercase and digit only

Trying this regex: `[ValidatePattern("**[^a-z][a-z0-9]**")]`.

But this does not match my requirements. I am elaborating below.

1. The first letter should lower case alphabet.
2. Restrict Uppercase.
3. Allow only lowercase letter and digit.
4. Single lowercase letter input also valid

Comment: Try `^[^A-Za-z][a-z0-9]*$` although I am not sure I understand the first requirement. `[^A-Za-z]` matches any 1 char other than ASCII letter. `[a-z0-9]*` matches 0+ digits or lowercase ASCII letters. If you need to accept all Unicode letters, you may write it as `^\P{L}[\p{Ll}0-9]*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, But this does not match my requirements. I am elaborating below.

1. The first letter should lower case alphabet.
2. Restrict Uppercase.
3. Allow only lowercase letter and digit.
4. Single lowercase letter input also valid

Comment: Yeah, please elaborate. It does not have to meet *your* requirements, only what I understand they are from your vague description.

Comment: just remove "^" symbol from you regex and you'll have it)

Comment: @2oppin If I remove the ^ symbol, This accepting "Ff" and not accepting "f" single letter.

my sample valid input is == (f, ff, f02, f665, fff, ff08) -------------------


do not accept == (F, FF, F02, fF, fF0....)

Comment: @HimalayKondekar Try `^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about PowerShell, but valid regex for this is:

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$
```

So please try:

```
[ValidatePattern("^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$")].
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze the requirements:

- The first letter should lower case alphabet - `[a-z]` / `\p{Ll}`
- Restrict Uppercase  - Just do not use them in the pattern
- Allow only lowercase letter and digit - `[a-z0-9]`
- Single lowercase letter input also valid - add `*` after the `[a-z0-9]` pattern to match 0 or more occurrences of it

Use

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Urq74I/1).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew